# xcode import filename collision

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Let's say I'm trying to use one and only one 3rd-party library in an xcode project - a pretty typical scenario, seemingly harmless.

I plug in the path location of my include files to the project's "header file search path" setting. I haven't even modified any code to make use of the code in the library yet.

It turns out that the project couldn't compile.

Xcode complained something like "Cannot find interface declaration for NSObject", which is pretty absurd. By examining the Build Result, the complained error comes from a header file of the 3rd-party library - it looks something like
[image]

So it is indicated in the Build Result that xcode is mistaken that Foundation.h is referring to the assert.h of that 3rd-party library instead of the iOS' built-in assert.h (4th sub-item)

Is there a way to fix the collision of the file names of #import include files?

(Needless to say, I'm new to obj-c -___-)

Comment: `#import <System file here>`, `#import "Own files here"`.

Comment: As said, I haven't modified any code (including adding any #import statement), so it won't be the reason of the error.

what I did is just add a path to "header file search path"

Comment: What third party library are you using? I think that looking at the source of that project could clarify things a bit.

Comment: it is j2objc: https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/

Comment: Strange, it  seems like there's something very wrong: it _does_ check the right `Foundation.h`, but does not find NSObject. I'm afraid I can't help you with this. +1 though, for finding such a strange bug.